# como crear un boton "mostrar más" cada X cantidad de divs con jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

busque diferentes formas pero no logro hacer que, por ejemplo, tengo 5 divs y al final de estos existe un botón "mostrar mas" y este botón muestre otros 5 divs más sin ocultar los anteriores, de modo que ese mismo botón siga debajo de los de 10 divs en total, nuevamente este botón muestra otros 5 divs... así hasta que no existan mas divs.

```js
<script>
function myFunction(idButton) {
  var Div1 = document.getElementById('Div1');
  var Div2 = document.getElementById('Div2');
  var Div3 = document.getElementById('Div3');


 switch(idButton) {
 case 1:
          Div1.style.display = 'block';
          Div2.style.display = 'none';
          Div3.style.display = 'none';
    break;

 case 2:
          Div1.style.display = 'block';
          Div2.style.display = 'block';
          Div3.style.display = 'none';
    break;

 case 3:
          Div1.style.display = 'block';
          Div2.style.display = 'block';
          Div3.style.display = 'block';
    break;

default:
          alert("error.")
        }

   }
</script>
```

```html
<div style="display:block;">
<div>Div1</div>
<div>Div2</div>
<div>Div3</div>
<div>Div4</div>
<div>Div5</div>
<button onclick="myFunction(1)">Mostrar más</button>
</div>

<div id="Div1" style="display:none;">
<div>Div1</div>
<div>Div2</div>
<div>Div3</div>
<div>Div4</div>
<div>Div5</div>
<button onclick="myFunction(2)">Mostrar más</button>
</div>

<div id="Div2" style="display:none;">
<div>Div1</div>
<div>Div2</div>
<div>Div3</div>
<div>Div4</div>
<div>Div5</div>
<button onclick="myFunction(3)">Mostrar más</button>
</div>

....
```

La única forma que se me ocurrio es usar los codigos de mostrar y ocultar usando sólo **display:block**, el problema es que el botón "Mostrar más" del div anterior no puedo ocultarlo y ademas que debo modificar TODO el código cada vez que agregó un nuevo div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero observa que no tienes un div3 y lo estas tratando de ocultar `Div3.style.display = 'none';` eso es null y te dara error, Puedes usar u contador para ver la cantidad de clic que ha dado el usuario:

```html
<script>
        var clic =0;
        function myFunction(idButton) {
            clic++;
            var Div1 = document.getElementById('Div1');
            var Div2 = document.getElementById('Div2');
            var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
            
            console.log(clic)
            clic = clic<3 ? clic : 1

            switch(clic) {
               case 1:
               Div1.style.display = 'block';
               Div2.style.display = 'none';
               
               
               break;

               case 2:
               Div1.style.display = 'block';
               Div2.style.display = 'block';
               
               break;

               case 3:
               Div1.style.display = 'block';
               Div2.style.display = 'block';
               
               
               break;

               default:
               alert("error.")
           }

       }
   </script>


   <div style="display:block;">
    <div>Div1</div>
    <div>Div2</div>
    <div>Div3</div>
    <div>Div4</div>
    <div>Div5</div>
</div>
<div id="Div1" style="display:none;">
    <div>Div1</div>
    <div>Div2</div>
    <div>Div3</div>
    <div>Div4</div>
    <div>Div5</div>
</div>
<div id="Div2" style="display:none;">
    <div>Div1</div>
    <div>Div2</div>
    <div>Div3</div>
    <div>Div4</div>
    <div>Div5</div>
</div>
<button id="btn" onclick="myFunction(1)">Mostrar más</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

con javascript puedes añadir nuevos div's al div padre, pero debes de sacar el boton del div padre y ponerlo debajo, algo asi:

```
<div style="display:block;" id="padre">
<div>Div1</div>
<div>Div2</div>
<div>Div3</div>
<div>Div4</div>
<div>Div5</div>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Mostrar más</button>
```

y con javascript obtienes el contenido del div padre y le concatenas los nuevos divs que vas a agregar algo asi:

```
function myFunction(){
   var div = document.getElementById("padre");
   var content = div.innerHTML;

   var new_content = "<div>Div6</div><div>Div7</div><div>Div8</div><div>Div9</div><div>Div10</div>";

   div.innerHTML = content + new_content;
}
```

No sé si exactamente este código vaya a funcionar, pero lógicamente así seria

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ir agregando `div` a medida que vas clickeando el botón y validar si ya existen `x` número de *divs* para bloquear el botón u ocultarlo y así no mostrar más *divs*, te dejo este código y espero te ayude en algo o te de una idea de como lograr tu objetivo:

```js
//Iniciamos variable que controlará los nombres de los div
var numeroDiv = '3';

function mostrarMas(element) {

  //Guardamos los div que queremos agregar, en este caso sólo 2
  let divsNuevos =
    `<div>Div${numeroDiv++}</div>
   <div>Div${numeroDiv++}</div>`;

  //Agregamos los div al contenedor que queremos
  $('#divPadre').append(divsNuevos);

  //Validamos si los div ya excedieron los 8 para no permitir añadir más
  if ($('#divPadre').children('div').length > 8) {
    
    //Bloqueamos el botón 'mostrar más'
    $(element).prop('disabled', true);
    alert('Ya no puedes agregar más <div>');
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divPadre">
  <div>Div1</div>
  <div>Div2</div>
</div>
<button onclick="mostrarMas(this)">Mostrar más</button>
```